# Error while opening exported Excel file

Tags: java, jquery, excel, export

I am trying to export html table into excel file by using jquery plugin. I tried lots of plugins but every time while opening the exported excel file it shows the warning message "File format is different than the extension specified". However, Contents in the file are correct. How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Please provide your code that is generating the excel file. Can you also provide the output - the generated xls file. Otherwise it's difficult to help you...

Comment: The jquery we are using is table2excel.js.We are using following code to export data.   $("#mybtn").click(function() {
 
 $("#grid_myGrid_body").table2excel({
  exclude: ".noExl",
  name: "Excel Document Name",
  filename: "myFileName"
 }); 
/*   window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + $('#grid_myGrid_body').html());
     e.preventDefault(); */
    
 });

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the error says: "File format is different than the extension specified"

Excel has two native formats: `.xls` and `.xlsx`

In addition, it can open a variety of other formats, such as:

- CSV (comma-separated values, usually `.csv`)
- TSV (tab-separated values, usually `.txt`)
- SpreadSheet XML (usually `.xml`)

If the file extension doesn't match the file format, Excel will correctly auto-detect the format, but will warn you that you may not be opening the file correctly.

Only way to prevent warning, is to make sure file is in a native format, and the file extension is correct.

So, depending on the plugin you used (you didn't day which!), you assigned the incorrect file name (extension).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.We are using table2excel jquery plugin.We are trying to create a xls format file.When we used xlsx format, file  was created although we  were unable to see any data.

Comment: The plugin is generating Spreadsheet XML, so unfortunately you cannot get Excel to stop warning you that your file extension differs from the format. It's just how the new security features of Excel works,